# GET Link with PHP

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

Why is this not working?

```
echo "<a href='update.php?'".$row['name']."''>Go</a>";
```

Thanks...It goes to update.php?

Comment: So what happens? and And what does the link look like if you do a "View Source" in your browser?

Comment: it just goes to update.php?  nothing after ?

Comment: Are there any characters in $row['name'] that need encoding? e.g. spaces, ampersands, question marks?

Comment: Please always look at the *final generated HTML code* - that will make it crystal clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

you have a typo with quotes :

```
echo "<a href='update.php?".$row['name']."'>Go</a>";
```

this should be better

Comment: Ugh, should've seen that before posting my answer. I'm just not used to have single-quotes contain the value of an attribute. Which I believe should be double-quotes according to the standard. Sharp eye!

Comment: @sarthaksss, you should accept this as answer because of it's oldness.

Answer (score 1):

Extra quote here

Change it to

```
echo "<a href='update.php?".$row['name']."'>Go</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and request the page again. It will most likely warn that the index `name` doesn't exist or `$row` isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

because you're closing the a link after the ? with a second '

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the typo in the quotes is the problem.
Make life a little easier:

```
$link = sprintf('<a href="update.php?%s">Go</a>', $row['name']);
echo $link;
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Comment: @mickmackusa well that is true if you want to write code that renders things that way, else `sprintf` is more useful as you can prepare all of the content ahead of rendering and thus avoid output buffering